# how do I convert a promise to observable in a Ionic 4 firebase PWA app

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

The following code worked previously with an Ionic/Cordova App that I built.  I am attempting to build an Ionic PWA app reusing some previous code    But now the

```
public List: Observable<any>;
```

does not seem to change the

```
this.List = this.messageService.getMessageList().valueChanges();
```

to an Observable and now returns the Uncaught (in promise): error.  I have previously used the this.List to return the firebase data and display it.  I have gone through my package.json data and I am still using the same rxjs, firebase and anglefire.  The only missing pieces are the Firebase Cordova plugins.  Any ideas what I am missing?

message.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../../services/messages/message.service';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message.page.scss'],
})

export class MessagePage implements OnInit {
  public List: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private messageService: MessageService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  this.List = this.messageService.getMessageList().valueChanges();
  console.log('List', this.List);
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MessageService {
  public messageList: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private firestore: AngularFirestore

  ) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.messageList = this.firestore.collection(
        `/posts`, ref => ref.orderBy('created')
        );
    });
  }

  getMessageList(): AngularFirestoreCollection<any> {
    return this.messageList;
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "pwa",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.1.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^1.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^1.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^1.3.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^6.4.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: how do u resolve the observable in the template?

Comment: What is the exact error? .valueChanges() does itself return an observable.

Comment: List won't display you the data as it is an observable. You need to subscribe to it firstly to get the data and then set it to a variable.

Comment: Please post your `package.json`

Comment: My exact error is [Error] ERROR – Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.messageService.getMessageList().valueChanges')

Comment: I just built an Ionic Cordova App with the Firebase Cordova, AngleFire plugins and the above code works fine

Comment: Google chrome dev tools show this error   ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `messageList` in the `MessageService` constructor asynchronously and its still undefined when you're calling `getMessageList()` in your `MessagePage`.

If `messageList` is fetched asynchronously you have to provide `messageList` as an  Observable in some way. If you only ever need the `valueChanges` you can initialize an Observable that maps the `authState` to your collection changes. If you want / need to fetch the collection in the constructor of your Service right away you can subscribe right there and use `shareReplay` to supply late subscribers in your Component with the last fetched value.

```js
public messageList: Observable<any>;

constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
  this.messageList = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => this.firestore.collection(
      `/posts`, ref => ref.orderBy('created')
    ).valueChanges()),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
  this.messageList.subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a promise to an observable by using Rxjs, there is a function called fromPromise which converts promise to observable.